# Can I combine variable assignent with an if?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
let fd = libc::creat(path, FILE_MODE);
if fd < 0 {
    /* error */
}
```

the equivalent in C is shorter:

```
if ((fd = creat(path, FILE_MODE)) < 0) {
    /* error */
}
```

can I do a similar thing in Rust? I tried to map it to `if let` but it looks like handling `Option`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible by design. `let` bindings are [one of the two non-expression statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/functions.html#expressions-vs-statements) in Rust. That means that the binding does not return any value that could be used further.

Bindings as expressions don't make a whole lot of sense in Rust in general. Consider `let s = String::new()`: this expression can't return `String`, because `s` owns the string. Or what about `let (x, _) = get_tuple()`? Would the expression return the whole tuple or just the not-ignored elements? So ⇒ `let` bindings aren't expressions.

About the `if let`: Sadly that won't work either. It just enables us to test if a destructuring works or to put it in other words: destructure a refutable pattern. This doesn't only work with `Option<T>`, but with all types.

---

If you *really* want to shorten this code, there is a way: make `c_int` easily convertible into a more idiomatic type, like `Result`. This is best done via extension trait:

```
trait LibcIntExt {
    fn to_res(self) -> Result<u32, u32>;
}

impl LibcIntExt for c_int {
    fn to_res(self) -> Result<u32, u32> {
        if self < 0 {
            Err(-self as u32)
        } else {
            Ok(self as u32)
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can use `if let` in the resulting `Result`:

```
if let Err(fd) = libc::creat(path, FILE_MODE).to_res() {
    /* error */
}
```

Comment: Or if you return a `Result` as well and want to return errors straight away, just `let fd = try!(libc::creat(...));`